# Error al compilar: 'was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++

A la hora de compilar este código, el compilador se queja del siguiente error:

> **error**: 'contenido' was not declared in this scope

Cuando aparentemente está declarado como parámetro de entrada en la función macro.

```
#include <iostream>
#define mostrar    (contenido) cout << "Resultado  " #contenido "==" << ":" << contenido << endl;
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int ai[] = { 2,3 };
    int zl = ai[0] + ai[1];
    mostrar(zl);

    int* pt1 = ai;
    int z3 = *pt1;
    mostrar(z3);

    int* pt2 = ai;
    int z4 = *(++pt2);
    mostrar(z4);

    int *pt3 = ai;
    int z5 = *pt3 + *(++pt3);
    mostrar(z5);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Te importaría [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/76848/edit) tu pregunta y formatear adecuadamente el codigo ? Tal y como está, no se sabe si el problema es del formateo o real. Y puedes aprovechar para indicar el error que obtienes.

Comment: Normal que no compile, has puesto `>` al principio de casi cada línea y eso no tiene sentido en [tag:c++].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se debe a que en las macros la definición de funciones no debe de haber espacios entre el nombre de la función y la lista de parámetros. Por ello si se borra el espacio  entre `mostrar` y `(contenido)` debería de funcionar:

```
#define mostrar(contenido) cout << "Resultado  " #contenido "==" << ":" << contenido << endl;
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya compiló. La verdad no pensé que fuera eso dado que en libro venía así.

Comment: @Mariano De acuerdo, gracias por el consejo. Proceso a editarla ;)